# How to send a picture through Viber?

Tags: android

I wonder how is it possible to send a picture through Viber.
 How do I send it using android application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802308/sending-image-over-viber

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334647/how-to-share-drawable-image-via-viber-and-google-hangout